# Build a mex file under Visual Studio ultimate 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mex

I had some code (c++) and I would like to generate the mex files.

is there any tutorial which tech how to setup visual studio ultimate 2012 how to build mex files?

thanks a lot

Comment: I haven't been able to actually try this in VS2012 yet, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716821/how-to-build-mex-file-directly-in-visual-studio-2010) question might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the same steps as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716821/how-to-build-mex-file-directly-in-visual-studio-2010) work for Visual Studio 2012 (and for Visual Studio 2013 too). Starting with an empty project the following settings in the project's Property Pages are necessary and sufficient to build a working .mexw64 file:

```
Configuration properties -> General:
    Set Target Extension to .mexw64
    Set Configuration Type to Dynamic Library (.dll)

Configureation poperties -> VC++ Directories:
    Add $(MATLAB_ROOT)\extern\include; to Include Directories

Configuration properties -> Linker -> General:
    Add $(MATLAB_ROOT)\extern\lib\win64\microsoft; to Additional Library Directories

Configuration properties -> Linker -> Input:
    Add libmx.lib;libmex.lib;libmat.lib; to Additional Dependencies

Configuration properties -> Linker -> Command Line:
    Add /export:mexFunction to Additional Options
```

`$(MATLAB_ROOT)` is the path to Matlab's root folder, eg. C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a. For a 32-bit build you'd need to change both occurrences of 64 to 32.

Comment: I hope my edit justifies undeleting and removing any downvotes from an answer that provides the requested solution.