# Faking a mex call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, mex

I have a visual studio project that creating a mex function. The solution has One project with one cpp file that is configured to generate a mex32/64 file.

I would like to fake a matlab call to this function for debugging/testing/validating.
My goal is to create another project, console application that calls this mexfuntion.
Has anyone ever done it? What are the parameters I should call to mexfunction with? How does the main() in the console application should look like?

Comment: A mex file is just a DLL (on Windows) with a `.mexw` extension.  You should be able to call the function it contains as you would call a function in any other DLL.  I expect your favourite search engine will find examples for you to follow.

Comment: You could always debug it in Visual Studio via MATLAB. [See this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23653347/2065121) for details.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I know but it is very clumsy. I would like a test project to test the dll functionality.