# MEX options when compiling with Visual Studio

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, mex

For some reasons I have to compile my MEX files under the Visual studio environment. There are many tutorials and my MEX files are working fine. However, there are a few MEX options, say `-largeArrayDims` in `mex` options, which I do not know where to turn on under the VS environment. Can anyone offer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-largeArrayDims` option is a switch to the `mex` command in MATLAB that simply indicates not to define `MX_COMPAT_32`.  So, in Visual Studio, you don't have to do anything since this is not defined by default.  If you want the opposite behavior (`-compatibleArrayDims`), then define `MX_COMPAT_32` in the Preprocessor section.  From tmwtypes.h:

**tmwtypes.h**

```C
#ifdef MX_COMPAT_32
typedef int mwSize;
typedef int mwIndex;
typedef int mwSignedIndex;
#else
typedef size_t    mwSize;         /* unsigned pointer-width integer */
typedef size_t    mwIndex;        /* unsigned pointer-width integer */
typedef ptrdiff_t mwSignedIndex;  /* a signed pointer-width integer */
#endif
```

In general, it is convenient to use a property sheet to set all the necessary settings for building a MEX file (library dependencies, headers, MEX-file extension, etc.).  A single property sheet that works automatically for either 32-bit or 64-bit MATLAB can be found [at GitHub](https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/tree/master/propertySheets).

Add the property sheet to each build configuration for the MEX project in the Property Manager (right click on the configuration such as `Debug | x64` and select "Add Existing Property Sheet".  See [this post for detailed instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391300/2778484).

A few additional notes:

1. I prefer to use `/EXPORT:mexFunction` instead of a .def file.  With a single exported function, this is much simpler.
2. The property sheet makes a manifest file, but it's really not necessary.
3. I include libut.lib, which provides a few nice functions for detecting a break (CTRL-C) from within a MEX file.  The relevant declarations (although this is way off topic here):

```C
// prototype the break handling functions in libut (C library)
extern "C" bool utIsInterruptPending();
extern "C" void utSetInterruptPending(bool);
```

Comment: Thanks and this is very helpful. So the process is, I make an XML file and incorporate it in the configuration? Does the mex command execute the same process when calling the CL compiler (or Linker)?

Comment: @JasonYuan The content of the files is XML, yes, but it should be saved `with a .props extension`.  The `mex` command essentially configures the build (compile and link) the same way.  Just try the `-v` switch when you run `mex` to see the different command lines used.  These property sheets set things up to do the same thing from Visual Studio.