# Building mex file (mexgdal) in Visual Studio or Matlab (same errors: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol)?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, visual-studio, mex

I am trying to compile mexgdal.c in visual studio 2013 and keep coming across the LNK2001 error for Gdal functions (like GDALOpen, GDALAllRegsiter, GDALGetRasterBand, etc.)

I've tried the solutions outlined in this question and it eliminated 19 out of 49 errors: [Building a MATLAB mex file in Visual Studio gives "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mexPrintf referenced in function mexFunction"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220193/building-a-matlab-mex-file-in-visual-studio-gives-lnk2019-unresolved-external-s)

but I still have the same error.

example code:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GDALGetDataTypeSize referenced in function mexFunction
```

I come across the exact same errors compiling in Matlab (except its error LNK2019 in Matlab)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Add the Gdal libraries to the additional library dependencies setting in the Linker properties tab.

Comment: I had done that previously and it still came up with the same error