# Building .mex file in Visual Studio 2015 for Matlab R2015A

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, caffe

I'm trying to build a fork of Caffe for Windows as a `.mex` file to be used in MATLAB (R2015A) code. In this fork there are `.mexa64` files present, but since I'm on a Windows machine I have to rebuild as `.mex`/`.mexw64`.

I've finally got `cmake` to work with all the various dependencies and generate `.sln` project files. I have Visual Studio 2015 installed.

I tried this solution:
[Building a MATLAB mex file in Visual Studio gives "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mexPrintf referenced in function mexFunction"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220193/building-a-matlab-mex-file-in-visual-studio-gives-lnk2019-unresolved-external-s?rq=1)
But I'm currently getting over 1000 errors of various types (syntax error, cannot open file, undeclared identifier, etc.), so I'm probably doing something very wrong.

How would I go about creating my `.mexw64` files in VS2015 (or in MATLAB if possible)?

**EDIT**: Got rid of a bunch of errors by including dependency folders in the Configuration Manager and following: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1761. Still loads to go..

Comment: we cannot help as we don't know how you have the project configured

Comment: Go to a temp folder in MATLAB and run "copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mex','yprime.c'),'.','f'); mex('-v','yprime.c')". This should list all the libraries used by mex when compiling. Make sure you are including those in your project.